# How to re-order operators in a String?

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm attempting to reorder a '/' operand so that it appears first

so `(1 + y) / (1 + 2z)^2` is converted to

```
/(1+y)(1+2z)^2
```

This code accomplishes this :

```
object ast extends App {

  val s: List[String] = "1 + y / 1 + 2z ^2".split(" ").toList;

  val removeOperatorsToBeReordered : List[String] = {
    s.filter(f => !f.contains("/"))
  }

  "/" :: removeOperatorsToBeReordered foreach(println)

}
```

But this is a simple test case and doesn't cater for (1 + x) / (1 + y) / (1 + 2z)^2 as '/' is added explicitly using `("/" :: removeOperatorsToBeReordered)`

`(1 + x) / (1 + y) / (1 + 2z)^2` should generate  `/ (1 + x) (/(1 + y) / (1 + 2z))^2`

Do I need some form of ast for this :

```
val generateAST = {
    case class Node(operand: String, leftOperator: String, rightOperator: String)
  }
```

Comment: You need to write a parser that produce an "expression" AST from the string. Then, converting from infix to prefix will be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, you need some kind of AST. Your current list doesn't even care about parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the string into a syntax tree of Nodes.

Take a look at [scala parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators).  You can define your own parsers and combine them to generate a nested structure of Nodes, then process the nested structure.

It seems like you want to parse the string to polish notation.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/bitwalker/6111452) is an example of a reverse polish notation parser.